# Swift2 extra argument in call error

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a problem with this code I get this error

> "Extra argument 'error' in call"

I marked the line where I found the error.

```
@IBAction func sendChat(sender: UIButton) {
// Bundle up the text in the message field, and send it off to all
// connected peers

    let msg = self.messageField.text!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,
                                                       allowLossyConversion: false)

    var error : NSError?



    self.session.sendData(msg!, toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers,
        withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable, error: &error)


    if error != nil {
        print("Error sending data: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    self.updateChat(self.messageField.text!, fromPeer: self.peerID)

    self.messageField.text = ""
}
```

Comment: The "Related" column is full of questions and answers about that error. The API are different but the solution is always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before Swift 2, we used to use syntax like so:

```
var error: NSError?
session.sendData(msg!, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, withMode:.Unreliable, error: &error)
if error != nil {
    print("Error sending data: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

The Swift 2 error handling paradigm employs `do`-`try`-`catch` (note, there is no `error` parameter, as the error is now "thrown", and handled within the `catch` block):

```
do {
    try session.sendData(msg!, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, withMode: .Unreliable)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error sending data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

You are using the old syntax with newer version of Xcode, so the compiler is warning you that this `error` parameter is no longer needed.

Please refer to the [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) chapter of *The Swift Programming Language.*